# Versions of npm packages

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I installed **Express** and the package.json shows me `"express": "^4.14.0"`. But when i do `npm express -v` via console inside my project, it gives me 3.8.8. Can somebody explain, where the different versions come from and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your project run `npm install` and
then run `npm list express` to see the version inside your project.

run `npm -g list express` to check if it may have been installed globally.

Comment: Did both. It gives me `express@4.14.0` locally and  `express@4.13.4` globally. `npm express -v` still gives me 3.8.8. Also, express behaves like a v3 install.

Comment: @Hinrich run `npm -g list npm`, I don't think `npm express -v` is valid it may be giving you the npm version instead